# How to properly assign correlated types to methods

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I'm trying to better understand the type inferance rules and I have a contrived example that is stumping me:

**The setup:**

```
interface Model{
    label?: string;
}

interface View<T>{
    cid?: string;
    model?: T;
}

class Foo {
    findWithModel<TModel extends Model, TView extends View<TModel>>(value: TModel): TView;
    findWithModel(value: string): any {
        return {cid: "2"};
    }
}

class AModel implements Model{
    constructor(public label: string){}
}

class AView<T extends Model> implements View<T>{
    cid = "1";
    model = null;
}

let f = new Foo();
let model = new AModel("test");
```

So I have an overload, `findWithModel` and in one case it's returning `any` and the other it should effectively be a returning `SomeView<SomeModel>` the issue comes in as follows:

```
let trial1 = f.findWithModel<AView<AModel>, AModel>(model);
let trial2: AView<AModel> = f.findWithModel(model);
```

So `trial1`, that works, but obviously that's pretty verbose to the point of why bother. Seems like extra work to pass `AModel` **2x**

So I assumed, you know I should just be able to provide the type info on the result declaration, `trial2` but typescript then sees that as:

```
Foo.findWithModel<AModel, {}>(value: AModel): {}
```

This obviously fails:

```
Property 'cid' is missing in type '{}'
```

Is this even possible to pull off without the overly verbose invocation where I pass the `AModel` **2x**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind getting back `View<T>` instead of the more specific type which you pass in the generic constraint, then you can just do:

```
findWithModel<TModel extends Model>(value: TModel): View<TModel> {
    ...
}

let trial1 = f.findWithModel(model); // type of trail1 is View<AModel>
```

Comment: fair enough! using that I can also just cast it to the more specific type `let result = <AView<AModel>> f.findWithModel(model);` Perhaps more importantly I'm not missing anything, it just cannot be done as illustrated in my example at this time. Thank you.